# Cache external embed pdf with javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, object, pdf, embed

I have the following external pdf embedded as shown below. The pdf displays fine, but how do I cache the pdf so that the page doesn't redownload the pdf each time I visit the page? Should I use an object tag instead?

```
<embed src="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="500" height="375">
```

Comment: why don't you use a php file instead and then send additional headers to tell the browser to cache the file? Then use php to serve the pdf file. Browser will treat the file just like a pdf but caches rules will be set.

Comment: I am using django, not php. Also I have to get the image on the client side for reasons I won't get into. Is there some way to have the client download the image?

Comment: django or php -> same process. Caching is not done through client side coding but from the server side. Proper headers do the job just fine.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, I have to get the external server to add the headers? If you are talking about my server adding headers, this i s not possible because I have to get the image client side as mentioned.

Comment: "get the image clinet side?" if the image is already on the client side, when do you need to cache. I'll a full answer to your problem to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you have a pdf on your server that you would like to cache onto the client side so that the pdf is not redownloaded each time the user refreshes the page.

By sending the proper headers, you can enforce cache rules (or at least try to enforce them as any browser can overrule your rules).

Php or in your case, Django, can send the appropriate headers to tell the browser to cache this pdf. My recommendation would be that you link that you provide in the embed tag links to a script instead of the pdf diriectly. This django script would sent out 2 sets of headers. One tells the browser to cache this content and other tells the browser it is sending a PDF file. This ensures that the pdf gets cached. When you load a webpage, the typical headers' scope by not encompass all external files/pdfs. As each is a separate request.

The method that I prescribed adds extra work than simply embedding the pdf but it should get the job done.

Comment: Extra - you can not force a client to "download" your image. Asking the browser to cache it is the ONLY way. PDF files are not always cached either. Good luck. Google can be your friend in these cases.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but you have misread my question. The pdf is not on my server. The pdf is on an external server. The client downloads the pdf by inserting the url in an <embed> tag. My server is not involved and I don't want it involved.